# Android Titanium App "invalid OAuth consumer key" Error

Tags: android, key, titanium, cloud, appcelerator-mobile

I have a problem with my first published Android Titanium App

In connection to the cloud I get this error:

"invalid OAuth consumer key"

The keys are properly septate

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on in the code, but not at the level of the server configuration, but had problems.

I created another service I changed the keys

so it all works

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Andrea, Please recheck all the 6 keys in your TiApp.xml file. This issue occurs when the **acs-oauth-key-production** is incorrect. I've marked the keys in the first picture. You'll get the original keys from [your applications](https://my.appcelerator.com/apps) as given in the second picture.

[image: keys]
[image: app settings]

Hope it resolved your issue

Comment: @AndreaGiglio : I got this error when I changed the keys. As per my knowledge it would be the only reason for that.

Comment: @AndreaGiglio: The Oauth Consumer key should be match with the acs-oauth-key-production. Try to copy the same from the app settings to the tiApp.xml